# R dplyr: calculate within-factor differences, for each factor independently

Tags: r, dplyr

*Alternative title:* **"For each group independently, calculate differences between its subgroups"**

I'm trying to calculate, for multiple factors independently, the difference in value for 1 level vs. the mean of all other levels within a given factor. In other words: if I have "Age" with 3  groups, I'd like to calculate the difference of score for group 1 as compared to the mean of the other 2 groups, etc.

The result would give an impression of how groups perform relative to one-another (I will be plotting the results). Using the overall mean isn't an option, since the results will be skewed (if for instance Age group "18-30" accounts for say 80% of the sample, the overall mean will be dominated by this one group).

Here's a reproducible example, and the code I have so far:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

# Data
df <- data.frame(score = sample(0:10, 20, replace=T), 
                 sex = sample(c("male","female"), 20, replace=T), 
                 age = sample(c("18-30","31-50","51-70"), 20, replace=T))

# Make data long
df_long <-
  df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-score, names_to = "factor", values_to = "level")

# Calculate level means
df_means <- 
  df_long %>%
    group_by_at(vars(factor, level)) %>% 
    summarise_all(mean, na.rm=T)

# Calculate within-factor differences, for each level
# ??
```

So far, my output looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   factor [2]
  factor level  score
  <chr>  <fct>  <dbl>
1 age    18-30   5.67
2 age    31-50   6.43
3 age    51-70   3.75
4 sex    female  5.92
5 sex    male    4.86
```

...but I'm looking to calculate a new column `diff` like so:

```
  factor level  score   diff
  <chr>  <fct>  <dbl>
1 age    18-30   5.67   .58
2 age    31-50   6.43   1.72
3 age    51-70   3.75   -2.30
4 sex    female  5.92   1.06
5 sex    male    4.86   -1.06
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around how best to use `group_by` and `summarise` to get to calculating the differences *within* each factor only? Any pointers very much appreciated!

PS. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41508454/1092247) gets close, but only works if there are just 2 levels within a factor.

Comment: You have "Age" with only 3 groups. Can you increase the sample data to more than 3 groups and show how the output would look like. Also it would be better if you use `set.seed` while generating the data for reproducibility.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, just edited. The exact number of groups in "age" doesn't really matter, it's more a question of how to calculate this whenever there are more than 2 groups within a give factor. And of course, how to calculate it for each factor independently! Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I don't get how you get the `diff` values that you have shown using the `score` values. Can you explain how do you get .58, 1.72 and -2.30 for `age` ?

Comment: I take the value of 1 group and subtract the mean of the other groups, e.g. for "18-30" I do `5.67 - mean(c(6.43, 3.75))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `factor` and use `map_dbl` to calculate `mean` within group.

```
library(dplyr)

df_means %>%
  group_by(factor) %>%
  mutate(diff = purrr::map_dbl(seq_along(score), ~score[.x] - mean(score[-.x])))
```

Comment: Incredible, this is perfect! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Base R Solution:

```
# Mean of each age: mean_df => data.frame
mean_df <- data.frame(lapply(split(df, df$age), 
            function(x){mean(x$score, na.rm = TRUE)}))

# Difference each mean in the group: mean_diff => list
mean_diff <- sapply(mean_df, `-`, mean_df)

# Add row.names as a vector: mean_diff_df => data.frame
mean_diff_df <- data.frame(cbind(vars = rownames(mean_diff), mean_diff), row.names = NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, though the end result is a matrix of differences, rather than a column of differences. As I show toward the end of my question, the idea would be to have a column of differences between 1 group and the mean of all other groups, within each factor independently?

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for something like this?

```
# Calculate the overall mean:
df_new = df %>% mutate(m_score = mean(score))

# Separately calculate the mean for both factors, create pivot and then add them together:
df_new %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  summarise(mean_level_score = mean(score),
            score_diff = mean_level_score - mean(m_score)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c("score_diff", "mean_level_score"), names_to = "factor", values_to = "level") %>% 
  bind_rows(df_new %>%
            group_by(age) %>%
            summarise(mean_level_score = mean(score),
                      score_diff = mean_level_score - mean(m_score)) %>%
            pivot_longer(-c("score_diff", "mean_level_score"), names_to = "factor", values_to = "level"))
```

Please note that the `score_diff` is now calculated by using the overall mean but not as "the difference in value for 1 level vs. the mean of all other levels within a given factor". I couldn't imagine any case where it might be useful to use the only the other factors' levels?!

Output looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  mean_level_score score_diff factor level 
             <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
1             5.43      0.379 sex    female
2             4.85     -0.204 sex    male  
3             5.17      0.117 age    18-30 
4             4.57     -0.479 age    31-50 
5             5.43      0.379 age    51-70
```

A `score_diff` of 0.379 in females means that their average score of 5.43 is 0.379 higher than the average score of 5.05 in the whole population. Similarly, people aged between 31-50 score on average -0.479 less than the average (of 5.05).

Sorry for the long code, this can be done much more elegantly I guess...

Comment: Great way of using the overall mean, although in fact I *am* looking to calculate within factors. In general, using the overall mean results in skewed statistics: if for instance age group "18-30" comprises 90% of the sample, then 90% of the overall mean comes from "18-30" -- in that case, comparing the "18-30" mean to the overall mean kind of becomes like comparing "18-30" to itself...

Comment: Hm, okay. Sorry that this won't help. I'm trying to imagine a solution, but you would have to do a lot of calculations, right? I mean, with up to 3 levels per factor this should be fine. But you would always need two calculations per level (level mean and the corresponding non-level mean). If this is an applicable method in statistics I could imagine that someone already made this into a package?! Maybe you could look into this rather than doing it by hand?

Comment: See the solution by @RonakShah, works a treat. Thanks for taking the time to try and find the solution!